# What does Carpenter169's prophecy mean?

Tags: world-of-darkness, hunter-the-reckoning

In *The Walking Dead*, a book for Hunter: The Reckoning, the character Carpenter169 delivers a prophecy on hunter-net:

> The hour of flame comes and the Emperor of Hell manifests. The twin-souled children of Jade have risen from their graves and await the hour that will sweep away those whose souls are not divided. The storm heralds the hour of destruction and its winds shall fan the flames even higher. Heaven's step children wander, blind into the kingdom of death, but their sight is keen. Rotten blood and rotten souls gather under the horns of blood. Fire shall not cleanse us, and our bones will be as sand."

I think I recognize a few isolated pieces here. For example, I'm pretty sure that the storm mentioned is the 6th Great Maelstrom. There is so much happening here that I can't figure out where to start my reading to decypher the rest.  The "Emperor of Hell" sounds like something from Demon, or maybe Wraith, or maybe Kindred of the East.... you get the picture.

What's this prophecy talking about?

An ideal answer would answer holistically (the big picture of the prophecy and how it fits into the World of Darkness), but also explain the individual references ("Emperor of Hell", "children of Jade", etc.).

Answer (score 7):

"The twin-souled children of Jade" are the kuei-jun, the Kindred of the East, who have both hun and p'o and are associated with the stone. Those whose souls are not divided are the Kindred.

"Heaven's step children wander, blind into the kingdom of death, but their sight is keen." These are the imbued themselves; they have access to the Messengers, and can see through supernatural deception, but they know nothing about the greater World of Darkness.

Comment: That makes sense. Would you consider adding a thesis statement? Something like, "The prophecy anticipates Event X?"

Answer (score 1):

While possibly not originally intended to (The Walking dead was published 2000), many of the threads seem to point to the current or later metaplots:

- "The twin-souled children of Jade have risen from their graves and await the hour that will sweep away those whose souls are not divided." The Cainites/Kindred (undead with one [lost] soul), are the mortal enemies of the Kuei-jin, who are pretty much exclusive to the Jade Empire A.K.A. eastern Asia, and who have two aspects to their soul, one of them from Yomi, the other from earth. The war between them is quite often detailed, for example in *San Fransico by Night* (2002), or in *Shadow War* (1999), which details such in chapter 5, crimson war.
- "The storm heralds the hour of destruction" could then refer to the Avatar Storm, which happened shortly before the *Year of the Scarab* (2001) and which wiped away the Wraiths and brought back Mummies - and eventually Demons.
- "Heaven's step children wander, blind into the kingdom of death, but their sight is keen." - This could refer to the Demons, fallen angels, many of them would further their plans after they were released by the Avatar Storm in 2002 (*Year of the Damned*).
- "Rotten blood and rotten souls gather under the horns of blood. Fire shall not cleanse us, and our bones will be as sand." - This might refer to the metaplot of *Year of the Damned* (2002), when the darkest parts of every splat would get their spotlight...

All in all, this apocalyptic picture matches a little what *Demon: Days of Fire* (2003) prophecies, and which then culminates in the book *Days of Judgement* (2004) - so might this even be an early reference to the end of the WoD? Especially it seems to point to the following chapters form Days of Judgement, in the order of the prophecy: [HtR] "Cleansing Fires", [Mummy:tA] "Apophis Ascends" [KotE] "Hollow Victories", [HtR] "Winds of Change", as well as the final Lucifer stroy.